# Can I make a order shift from A of B to B of A?

Tags: phrase-usage

The original sentence I encountered in my reading is shown as below:
1962RR is a 70-year-old right-handed man with 18 years of education.
What is strange for me is the chunk '18 years of education'.
Can I replace 18 years of education with the education of 18 years in this context?
Are both of them acceptable English expressions?

Answer (score 1):

No.

Although "with 18 years of education" does sound a little awkward, "the education of 18 years" is wrong.